# How to take String input with spaces in erlang with io:fread or io:read

Tags: string, erlang, erl

I just want to take a string input from the user in erlang programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is [`io:get_line/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#get_line-1):

```
1> io:get_line("enter data: ").
enter data: data with spaces
"data with spaces\n"
```